# Laravel Livewire pagination not working when there is custom link

Tags: pagination, laravel-livewire

When I try to paginate without passing parameters in the `{{ $dish->link() }}` it works perfectly fine.

But when I try to add custom template for it e.g. `('paginate:bootstrap-5')` it  doesnt work properly anymore (what i mean by that is the page refreshes when i switch to other page).

here is my livewire template

```
<div id="recipe_list" class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap">
    @foreach ($dish as $recipe)
        <div id="recipe_item" class="me-4 mt-2 p-2 d-flex flex-column text-center" :wire:key="$recipe->id">
            <img src="{{asset('img/profile_picture.jpg')}}" alt="">
            <p class="text-break font mt-2 fw-bold" id="ingredient_count">{{$recipe->ingredient_count}} Ingredients</p>
            <p class="text-break font" id="recipe_name">{{$recipe->dish_name}}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary text-white font">View</button>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <div id="pagination" class="d-block d-flex justify-content-center pt-2 mt-5">
        {{ $dish->links() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

My livewire comntroller

```
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Dish;
use App\Models\Ingredient;
use App\Models\DishImage;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Pagination extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public function getQueryString()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $dish = Dish::paginate(12);
        
        foreach ($dish->items() as $key => $value) {

            $dish[$key]->ingredient_count = Ingredient::where('dish_id', $value->id)->count(); 
        }   
        return view('livewire.pagination', [
            'dish' => $dish,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anw, I solved it already by going through livewire documentation https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/1.x/pagination "#Using A Custom Pagination View".

Comment: If the question was solved, consider marking the answer as accepted.